# Постфикс СЯ входит в основу глагола "возвращаться"?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

1) Постфикс СЯ всегда входит в основу глагола, или это зависит от того,  является ли он словообразующим или формообразующим?

2) Каким является постфикс в глаголе "возвращаться"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постфикс-ся обычно принято считать словообразующим,т.к. в большинстве случаев он вносит новое значение. Постфикс-ся включается в основу, если он словообразующий.

В вашем примере постфикс-ся входит в основу, т.к. это словообразующий постфикс, т.е. здесь он придает глаголу новое значение. Ср.: ***возвращать - возвращаться.*** ***Но: вращать — вращаться.*** Здесь постфикс-ся не меняет лексического значения глагола, т.к. это формообразующий постфикс.

[Постфикс-ся](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=719.gV7xRjr_BvYHpF9xWp9NDJ9KQ5d3FeAEoiJQnMtVGvX9YLRgqj_mhcHplz5Pe5mIO-p2qI8ZHY3YVCPyHmPFS08EEfJSNTyk-MhRjDkGxZ7mfbR1hDOAXHFf_aevXiV4.2d2b66e66307004a27c10f0679df06cad98c9640&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9aJ2gf1Q1OEQHP1rbfzHEMvZEAs4QuMnSA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxbm9KQ09JZlFRdlJrNW1UQXRhSnRIOW9tWnZwc1pRX2VCcG5CTG1FdmJVTlBSR25vNE1oS0xOQkpxaURwbURYNEdpQ0JfQUNYeC1iRFgzc2RwcEwyeTBVVnBVTjZVZWk2NEFVWXpwY2xGMDF3U1hhMjd5eGI1QWxhUXhfUjFqdUh0RElnUjBjZ1Vid3BZUnpKdnhJOExxS1Nzd00tX0pKb184YmtFT0I4aHhHQVNVbDVrTy1vMGpjZTJ5VGVaVzY1SF9uR0ZHMllZalU4ZkJDMVRQcGU1NlhBd2Z3OGU5cXd3&b64e=2&sign=bfb4d7b1466c8449efda990ba861f837&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQYtNprRPFzufqudLJZKAOLwoDTdQIxazSeWiChev90bYFecXuYsoEILqvbg4wNmD6I7hVi8fUyYw5jUesRXJvfAAQI88D9jV3TpAQ5M7ayzR9w6ugZNeLt-IFvyxmijqKxclQ1t5oYjBUVPxcPBFMSkmCMdlH7LH-cmzF7rQOOGxMbLRv2vlkr-8vUglHLuFPZdQmubUeRDc&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCHgI4h6Y0hbtoes4Cfdh8gAafn13g0sB7LVWXwK7RYloJDX0py-8vE7SP_EjA6P31sweapsKixfP_ZlkLpmSLhMxoNmFPdZAUJQxvli0fhMdY1EcomaFQJYTR8CgV3nBO0qDDP4ZDo1AX-nTyFjJabpTE_mPompyJYSVo2n2nk35Es8RqNtgh0RiXjlvCOGL26liZlIdE79t9wcmma9ixyHCsPXKRK212sw0qCl8BAVcjOxDG1J2OECbHEXH89rK1xoKza4bkIoJxcQJjpSwyRtodAL-wG6IZpdGVLpyqk0xt1AElxmO_xvxXfOquMIREcXS3PVl6Qm_a17JFXNvJbxnG9-CtrraO2JecFkfAvJrZVOI-pNIYqGVdUwldSlWJt2XUANh094U2RWShj2w6uoGpXPP04Z0xph93_0fAkrPYeeob6hNPn10gDKFG6Ocvu2UWOz_vhsJJQXRb8bJNvWLKBGZEYPV09-RaW9BqNR-IM8C5HNnPIEdAUOMqcER9ClIkX7XabLdoyw3SMA9NzEoDuIhTc0jG6mAJu9HVO68t3jsty-KDAiAGvF5BQm5poZ5geJ5HAWRRvju0D2CVZ2a1zo_NimjsMEMjbd7nsKebLBd1ycCPhJFwSG1p6Gu76WAEdpGf7gdiNerZLeqiltGBL-JU76Cy14ra08FRV1MFDruhYVgkF5ATP-rUiFf6sMa8inhZvql0QxuZpa8gyH0QoyZwcycyIg578CTbCyTNFcY1RDcjooGw4pOYpZMsP_wnWKkw8RlQjzDtgR6szji2r9fReV3grCcmEFjiyV_YdivbeeT7W2dCySxvzIVE1Gy7U9sMDUAjdmAtypK-QP4bo7PTOcKMIBsX8L_eEKuX-Y6e-UMBvwrvv_Y2rPzMiDXRFGK2RsGRgxEBUkEF9iuayvym6wYQgFoJLqmDQOhA-fwsK62gU47s4_qdwrtSP1pXtIDIvMzuVaDHOKnCxh_fL6_jR9CBXx1Fp_llWKfBuZv2JkinJQDIczB9wqsuQKWEQpq2BHEGLwXSSPIB0bcWpech9oPAfdaR2aP29-9QfGG_DOsJ0_TxfkHbgn1KG2ljHJTKu0SO-T_Yx1LOrpFhT3faKiAR5NG2wWNEJgIwWbudfYVuSViBNNE9ijwUh9Sn9IdExGKp16clIy1Y0_7OsUKSLx5wSg4FyjNaBqT0UcOF9SllKi_2JbYckPWa1HbUUCYY6X2Ivd7htMUSbKnf9JA_EZJ1sTGmquPWzcXy3nIqTGruqcjFvE2k7Jf_qWdyew1h5ul2SvMjospiZOZYfEh0ylzj6IUF5--ZbifeiUftppDIMHjSjKDThIB6q1xfUWOGTQTm-UAOAfNOUFEHCxWaZHDTxTN-KMma2q2OT0Ah1fE5OmiHnzMr9TITb-E51_6aIWTz-Y6BABclPAi192rTaZYjC7LrzS_sZ-4uEpkSth8L5MTjiDG7BrFWjFot-WZ4BK5nDAZDmGndnwv9VYku4Q7sbWbgvcv6dPDTgGWamsxszu45IpyOcjYGawOPwteK6cEWOS8eJEp9W0kEDw2FQO0LhBG2sGIRVUDKkh2g7v2ubFzI4Mo_7kj2ox-fzZN-oENwsVlU_mTnp-Y9lT_Ek43PNdonDRS8oUuncAAvufb-mQhfw-5N9eTwIfsX0MtrsgPY38NZqyg0WQ&l10n=ru&cts=1434267784446&mc=4.96127354787062)

Comment: А какое определение вы даете двум видам суффиксов (в каком случае они придают слову новое значение, а в каких нет)?  Мне пока кажется, что оба глагола в разных ситуациях  могут иметь постфикс СЯ с разными значениями. А вообще эта тема взята из форума  http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1590029-vhodit-li-postfiks-s-v-osnovu-slova-zapomnilos.html. (Но там ответ не показался мне убедительным).

Comment: Вера, я полностью согласен с автором статьи. Формообразующим он считается тогда, когда образует форму  залога, безличные формы глагола. Словообразующий, когда меняется значение слова. Иная точка зрения у к.ф.н. Крыловой Марины.

Comment: Вот что она пишет: ''Глагольный постфикс -ся (-сь) требует особого замечания. Он может быть и слово-, и формообразующим. Формообразующим он является, если образует форму залога: лить-ся, рассердить-ся, бросить-ся. В ряде случаев аффикс -ся приобретает значение словообразующей морфемы и входит в основу, которая в данном случае становится прерывистой (её прерывает окончание и/или формообразующий суффикс): расплака-ть-ся, вчита-л-ся, разгуля-вш-ий-ся. Отличить такие глаголы несложно: они не употребляются без -ся.

Comment: Но я не могу согласиться с этой точкой зрения. Бросить и броситься - эти глаголы с двумя разными значениями. Вера, в основном ответе я привел ссылку, прочитайте, тоже интересно.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Обязательно прочитаю и обдумаю ваш ответ, а также всю тему.

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема заключается в том, что  существуют два залога: возвратный и пассивный (противопоставленный активному залогу), которые в школе не изучаются и, соответственно, не различаются. Сравните: (1) Люди возвращаются. Спутник вращается (возвратный залог). (2) Вещи возвращаются владельцам. Колесо вращается ветром (пассивный залог). В случае возвратного залога СЯ входит в основу, такие варианты встречаются чаще. Кроме того, часть глаголов вообще не образуют залоговую пару (смеяться). И только в случае пассивного залога  мы имеем формообразующий суффикс, который не входит в основу.

Comment: Вера, тема эта недостаточно разработана. Некоторые лингвисты, как, например, автор той статьи, которую мы привели, считают постфикс-ся во всех случаях формообразующим, за исключением одного случая: когда слово без ся не употребляется. С такой точкой зрения я не согласен.